# hosting server changing a property of a word file

Tags: hosting

Someone today told me that a mistake while transferring a file from one hosting server to another actually changed the property of "Created Date" in one their microsoft word files to a new date (actually in the future)

Here's some more detail:
I think it's either windows or Linux probably shared hosting.

It is a wordpress pdf file (created by ms word on a mac) that he said was the "final" file created on a server a month ago next to the "draft" file both in the "uploads" directory.

At that time he said he forgot to change the link in the worpress front end from the "draft" to the "final" file.

Yesterday the person said he switched this link from the "draft" to the "final" file.

When rendered through a browser the document properties now show the file as created and modified on 2nd July rather than 5th June when he said it was created.

Is this possible for a server to affect a change like this? or would not the user need to actually open the file to make that change?

(hope that's a bit better for info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you've not detailed the transfer protocol but yeah, it's very possible.

Comment: Yes sorry I should have given more detail. I will edit the question to give more detail.

Answer (score 2):

The server will timestamp it with its own current date/time (depending on how it is transferred). If the server's clock is set ahead, the word doc will have a time stamp from "the future."

Comment: i see, but it would be the time that the document was placed on the server right?

Comment: I wanted to mark this as answer but feel bad toward first answerer because they were first, and I can't mark you up because I don't have enough reputation. sorry I can't do that